# How much do people pay to have their miniatures painted?

Tags: miniatures, pricing

I've been painting miniatures for a short while now and was wondering how much people usually pay to have their minis painted.

After researching a bit I've narrowed my options down. I've decided there are two possible ways that I could price the mini paint-jobs. Which do you think would be more practical?

1. Create a set price for each size of figure, regardless of complexity. (ie. 1 square-sized figure is this price, 2-square sized figure is that price, and so on) The price ranges I've discovered per piece is anywhere from $2.50-$4.00 per 1 square figure.
2. Base the pricing around the time it takes to paint the piece rather than the size. More like an "hourly wage". This way I could maybe make an average hourly rate and *potential customers could pay for a specific amount of time to be dedicated to each figure, etc.

Any advice is appreciated~

[image: Collection of 3]
![WIP][1]

[image: Earth Golemn]
![WIP][1]

Comment: Advice: act like a buyer for a while and go find out what people sell for (and where). Then you have your data. We can't replicate that market research for you. And besides which, even if we tried, it will vary enormously based on where you are and over time.

Comment: I see, well I will try that then. Thanks ^^

Comment: Aside, those are pretty nice paint jobs. I have no idea what the *range* of pricing tends to be, but you can probably demand something in the upper half of whatever range your research finds.

Comment: Haha thanks, I get a little carried away. I edited the question as well now that I've researched a little bit ^^

Comment: The current question, whilst valid, is primarily opinion based. We don't field opinion based questions, since they break down in our format.

Comment: By the way, you could set a price at the beginning based on your estimates of time & complexity, then charge that price. If you have a time/complexity blowout, you'll just get better at making estimates - you don't charge in addition to the already agreed-upon price. This is an option often used in consulting work, alongside your option #2 (pay by hour).

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for letting me know. It's really a consumer-based question so opinions are what I'm kind of looking for...I might try to estimate the time and complexity beforehand then. It sounds practical, I just don't want to overcharge and come off arrogant. ^^

Comment: You'll be a skilled artisan who knows the value of their work. Those who don't want to pay up won't accept the offer - they don't need to and you don't have to do anything about that. You can't control how people think so if someone thinks you're arrogant, that's their issue (and some people will think that and you'll have to take that in stride and not care)

Comment: @user9911 A general advice I was told at the end of my degree was: calculate your expenses and then add how much you feel you should be paid to be doing something other than X. X being surfing, playing games, visiting a friend etc.

Comment: Consumer based questions are much better for a proper survey. Sorry, this question will remain on hold.

Comment: Instead of asking "how much", perhaps the question should be "how to determine" instead. At that point, @SevenSidedDie's comment would be a really good answer.

Comment: @Ellesedil It still wouldn't be on topic, though.